# Xamarin forms listview group header template not working

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, grouping

I am trying to use the group header template in xamarin forms
I have followed the following article and implemented but no success
http://motzcod.es/post/94643411707/enhancing-xamarinforms-listview-with-grouping
even took suggestion from here 
http://www.infinite-x.net/2015/04/08/working-with-the-listview-groupheadertemplate/

if I put GroupDisplayBinding i will get normal style, even though I have template

```
<ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout
              VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              BackgroundColor="#009688">
              <Label  Text="{Binding Key}"  TextColor="White" Margin="10" FontSize="Medium" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
      </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
```

if I remove GroupDisplayBinding I will get my group class type in the group as shown in this image
[image: See the top header sthotraani.Common.Grouping that's my class]

collection code

```
private ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, MFullIssue>> _Issues;
        public ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, MFullIssue>> Issues
        {
            get { return _Issues; }
            set { _Issues = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

 SthotramService.service.Issues().ContinueWith((t) =>
            {
                var sorted = from c in t.Result
                             orderby c.IssueTypeName
                             group c by c.IssueTypeName
                             into theGroup
                             select new Grouping<string, MFullIssue>(theGroup.Key, theGroup);

                Issues = new ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, MFullIssue>>(sorted);
            });
```

collection object

```
public class MFullIssue
    {
        public int IssueID { get; set; }
        public int IssueTypeID { get; set; }
        public string Issue { get; set; }
        public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public string IssueTypeName { get; set; }
        public string IssueTypeDesc { get; set; }
        public List<MResolution> Resolutions { get; set; }
    }
```

grouping class

```
public class Grouping<K,T>:ObservableCollection<T>
    {
        public K Key { get; private set; }

        public Grouping(K key, IEnumerable<T> items)
        {
            Key = key;
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code containing the collection that is being bound to and the type of object in the collection.

Comment: @hvaughan3 updated the post with collection code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at my Grouped ListView code, your `GroupHeaderTemplate` needs to be a `DataTemplate`. Not sure if that is the root issue but will definitely cause problems later if not:

```
<ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            ...
```

Other than that, I do not see any issues with your code so you may need to make sure the groups in your `ObservableCollection` look correct.

Comment: First of all according to documentation 
GroupHeaderTemplate is mutually exclusive with ListView.GroupDisplayBinding. Setting this property will set ListView.GroupDisplayBinding to null. 
However my problem listview completely ignores Groupheadertemplate irrespective of displaybinding as I mention in my post if I put displaybinding I get name in default style if I dont put displaybinding I get my class name in the header

Comment: I think there's a bug in the ListView --> groupheadertemplate but not sure.  I have tried all possibilities. the listview is ignoring groupheadertemplate.

Comment: @Kris Its possible. It is working fine for me. Though instead of using the Grouping<> object in LINQ, I created a separate model to hold the groups, like Xamarin shows in the example.

Comment: Even I did the same, created a separate class for it. do you see any mistakes in my code above ? that's what I am using. updated the grouping class

Comment: hey it's working now :) not sure what caused it, maybe the <DataTemplate> tag I am missing. But I am sure I used datatemplate earlier. but it's working now. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Kris Awesome! Who knows what fixed it but just never touch the code again now that it works ;)